# Is there a jquery plug in for this? [context menu that triggers on click]

Tags: jquery, html, css, model-view-controller, menu

[image]
[image]

I have posted two self explanatory pictures of what I am looking for.
This is context menu. And I found many jquery context menu plugins. But they all trigger on right click. I am looking for a context menu plug in which is can be triggered on clicking of other html elements.

I dont want to do it manually because I will have to take care of a lot of things like,

- by default direction should be right and below the element.
- if there is no space, it should change the direction of display...
- and all good features of a fully developed plugin

**just looking for a Boolean answer weather something is there OR I will have to create it ?**

Comment: ContextMenu is the right-click one. Your examples is much more a "Drop Down Menu"

Comment: Would triggering a click event not be enough? http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: damn! people just enjoy clicking on that downvote button

Comment: hey @e2bady , that should do it.
can u please put that as an answer so that I can mark it resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By triggering the click-event through jquery.trigger(...) you can simulate a click on any element. Which solves the issue, of making a click event from anything you want to couple the functionality to.

See: [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) on jquery.trigger()

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an extra plug in for this task. You can create this very simple yourself. Here's an example code you can style to your needs. It toggles the menu on click on the "icon" and it also hides itself when a link from within context menu is clicked:

**HTML**

```
<a id="link">Icon to open menu</a>

<nav id="menu">
    <ol>
        <li><a>Some link 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Some link 2</a></li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var nav = $('#menu');

$('#link').click(function() {
    nav.fadeToggle(500);
});

nav.find('a').click(function() {
    nav.fadeOut(500);
});
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/Vr6SN/